# Specify MP3 Audio Width Via HTML5

Tags: html, audio, mp3

I have a website which is going to use `html5` to load and play MP3 files but the player isn't showing up correctly. My code is simply:

```
<audio width="440" height="auto" controls>
    <source src="a/attachments/<?php echo "$post_year/$post_id"; ?>.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

When I run the page, I am shown the player, but...

Even though I have specified a width of `440`, it only appears to be loading at about `300`.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong with this? Any ways to make the player look any different also?

Comment: Try CSS?.......

Comment: Meaning? Add CSS to the <audio> tag???

Comment: `<audio width="440" height="auto" controls>` change to `<audio style="width:100%" controls>`

Comment: I added a `class` and styled it in my .CSS file and it works fine now. Thanks. Any ideas why specifying a `width` of 440 in the code wouldn not work though?

Comment: I've answered your question. You can accept and/or upvote if you understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<audio width="440" height="auto" controls>` change to `<audio style="width:100%" controls>`

HTML width does not work because width attribute is deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: This works brilliantly. As does using a `class=""`, with the use of an external style sheet or internal style code, for anyone who wants to do it that way. Thanks Mehul.